# AsyncTaskLoader with Dialogs, Is it feasible?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager, asynctaskloader, android-loader

I started an new app and I wanted to use the latest patterns and guidelines for android, one of those is to use Loaders (AsyncTaskLoader) instead of AsyncTasks, I'm trying to see if Loaders are suposed to really replace all your AsyncTasks "tasks" i.e.

Let's say you want to build an app based on REST calls, one of those calls is in charge of login the user. So while you click submit (on a fragment button) a dialog comes up until the response gets back, if I'm correct the AsyncTaskLoader onLoadFinished won't let you dismiss a dialog unless you use a handler, and well using this, makes the solution look a bit hacky, cause then you need to show error dialogs like for when the username or password is wrong, and well you may end up with a bunch of calls to handlers.

I did this in a snap using an AsyncTask and all working ok, now that I was moving all the code to AsyncTaskLoader it seems I'm hacking many things when it's supposed to be easier, I'm a beginner so please be patient with your answers.

I appreciate the time you take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to see if Loaders are suposed to really replace all your AsyncTasks "tasks".

A `Loader` performs asynchronous loading of data, monitors the source of its data and delivers new results when the contents of its data changes. An `AsyncTaskLoader` is a `Loader` that uses an `AsyncTask` to offload the `Loader`'s operation to a separate thread. An `AsyncTask` is basically Android's version of a `Thread`; it abstracts out the tedious multithreading details and provides a few convenient callback methods.

In your case, logging in the user is a one-time, potentially expensive `REST` request... it has nothing to do with loading/monitoring a data source. You should use an `AsyncTask` instead.

Comment: On a separate note, you should try to avoid launching `Dialog`s in `onLoadFinished` in general... it's annoying and slows down the user experience.

Comment: so AsyncTaskLoaders are more related to adapters, and it's still valid to use an AsyncTask for non repetitive tasks like a login request right?

Comment: Yeah, basically... more specifically you should use `Loader`s when you are "loading data" asynchronously, and you should use an `AsyncTask` when you want to perform a single potentially expensive operation. :)

Comment: This is a common android problem, don't think you cae it alone. Up to now there is no real solution to this on android. Asynctasks are not pretty well suited for netwrok data loading, loaders are not neither.

Comment: A service would ideal for that, with caching. We are actually working on such a library at my job, we plan to publish and realease it open sourced.

Comment: @Snicolas I'd be curious to see it when it's released... link me if you remember :)

Comment: @Snicolas Yeah a service is a good option too, what I'm struggling is what's the most efficient solution taking in consideration time, maintainability and feasibility, without a library like what you are working on, in a small project it seems overwhelming to plan on creating a service just for a few REST calls to the server. Please don't take me wrong I love patterns, but compared to other languages it seems simple tasks like these are overcomplicated on android.